# How can I resolve Jar hell without using a heavy-weight framework?

Tags: java, jar

How can I avoid or resolve [Jar hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)? Without using a heavy-weight framework such as the well known [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) framework.
Let say we have two required dependencies which are supported no more that work stably with different versions of the same library? I need all that staff to work together.

Comment: What research have you already conducted? EDIT: The solution really is something anyone can implement pretty easily. Just knowing how classes are found and making your own class loaders and class finding. [Jar Hell made Easy - Demystifying the classpath with jHades](http://blog.jhades.org/classnotfoundexception-jhades-jar-hell-made-easy/) Seems helpful. Also look at child first loading, parent last.

Comment: Alternative to what? I believe that article talks about what it is and what can be done about it

Comment: I've searched a lot. I found some meterias how to try to implement by myself (using Class loader indepth) or use OSGi container which imply signifficant architectural changes. I would like to found some lightweight library that takes this as a primary goal

Comment: Use a coherent language, like C#. Problem solved.

Comment: @Krythic, you may want to dig some deeper into the C#

Comment: Without sources and citations, I'm just going to assume you have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the sonatype jarjar maven plugin to automatically create copies of dependant classes renamed into a different package.

This gives your library a private copy of its dependencies, thus preventing version conflicts with any other library it may be deployed with.

Remember that some software may have licence conditions that prevent you from making altered copies of it.

For example, the following pair of rules create a private copy of Apache commons-lang3. Apache commons-lang is usually deployed in a package called `org.apache.commons.lang3`, but here I create a copy of it in the package `com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.lang3`. The plugin automatically fixes all the places that my library uses Apache commons-lang3 to link to the copy.

```
<rule>
    <pattern>org.apache.commons.lang3.**.*</pattern>
    <result>com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.lang3.@1.$@2</result>
</rule>
<rule>
    <pattern>org.apache.commons.lang3.*</pattern>
    <result>com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.lang3.$@1</result>
</rule>
```

You can use the same approach to repackage third-party libraries with their own private copies of their own dependencies.

Here is the full example maven build configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jarjar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jarjar-classes</id>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jarjar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <input>{classes}</input>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jarjar-testclasses</id>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jarjar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <input>{test-classes}</input>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
        <includes>
            <include>com.google.inject:guice</include>
            <include>com.googlecode.lambdaj:lambdaj</include>
            <include>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</include>
            <include>com.google.guava:guava</include>
        </includes>
        <rules>
            <rule>
                <pattern>com.google.common.**.*</pattern>
                <result>com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.guava.@1.$@2</result>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <pattern>com.google.common.*</pattern>
                <result>com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.guava.$@1</result>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <pattern>com.google.inject.**.*</pattern>
                <result>com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.guice.@1.$@2</result>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <pattern>com.google.inject.*</pattern>
                <result>com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.guice.$@1</result>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <pattern>ch.lambdaj.**.*</pattern>
                <result>com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.lamdaj.@1.$@2</result>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <pattern>ch.lambdaj.*</pattern>
                <result>com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.lamdaj.$@1</result>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <pattern>org.apache.commons.lang3.**.*</pattern>
                <result>com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.lang3.@1.$@2</result>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <pattern>org.apache.commons.lang3.*</pattern>
                <result>com.lexicalscope.fluentreflection.internal.lang3.$@1</result>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer! Your solution will certainly work for 'my component' which is under my control, for which I can chose 'proper code in classpath'. What about two required dependencies which are supported no more that works stably with different versions of the same library? (updated my question)

Comment: You can use the same approach to repackage third-party libraries with private copies of their own dependencies.

Comment: As far as I understand, this would imply plenty of manual analisis and maven work. Anyway, thanks for working solution. I'm wondering if it is feasible to implement/reuse simple library that could change the way of finding the class at runtime: not to keep the only copy, one that would happen to be higher in classpath tree, but to keep all versions under proper classloader and chouse proper one at runtime. Just like OSGi do.

Comment: I don't see how you can do it at runtime without something pretty similar in weight to OSGi or Jigsaw. Perhaps the maven shade plugin can reduce the amount of maven work you need to do: http://jesseyates.com/2015/08/17/using-maven-shade-to-run-multiple-versions-in-a-jvm.html

Comment: OSGi is pretty heavy-weight because target area is pretty wide. I think if the problem, being discussed, would be some more annoying and worth time spent, we would see some awesome solution like google juice in comparison to Spring.

Comment: is the jarjar plugin out of maintenance and being supersede by maven-shade plugin?

Answer (score 0):

[Project Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) is on the horizon, and will be part of **Java 9**.

-> [Java Platform Module System (JSR 376)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/)